# Where and how to store txt files created periodically in Spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, txt

I have a scheduled task which periodically creates a txt file for statistics. I have to write some content into txt files and store them somewhere. Each time a new txt files should be created with name "statistics-'new Date()'.txt". I have no idea how to create them and store.

```
@Service
public class NewsSourceServiceImpl implements NewsSourceService {

    private final NewsSourceRepository newsSourceRepository;
    private final ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler;
    private final CronTrigger cronTrigger;

    public NewsSourceServiceImpl(NewsSourceRepository newsSourceRepository, ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler, CronTrigger cronTrigger) {
        this.newsSourceRepository = newsSourceRepository;
        this.threadPoolTaskScheduler = threadPoolTaskScheduler;
        this.cronTrigger = cronTrigger;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void statisticalTask() {
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.schedule(new StatisticalTask(), cronTrigger);
    }

    private class StatisticalTask implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            List<Statistics> statisticalTasks = newsSourceRepository.countNewsForStatistics();
            // Here I have to create a txt file and 'statisticalTasks' contents. Then store the files.
        }
    }

}
```

I have tried to use 'logback-spring.xml' when we try to store log files. But, I think this approach is not appropriate here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can save wherever you want to, good practise would be to create a folder with suitable name like `stats` in project root directory. So the absolute path might look like `/home/user/IdeaProjects/project-name/stats/file-name.txt`
2. You can use built in `File` and `Writer` from `java.io` package

```
        String directoryPath = "stats";
        String fileName = "file-name.txt";

        File directory = new File(directoryPath);
        if (!directory.exists()) {
            directory.mkdirs(); // Create the directory if it doesn't exist
        }

        File file = new File(directory, fileName);

        try (Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file))) {
            String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            String contents = "first line"
                    + newLine
                    + "next line";

            writer.write(contents);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```